# using alert in template gridview to show hidden value of different column

Tags: gridview, cell, alert

I stumbled on the solution to this on this board and set up my program to use it. I even posted comment that it was a great solution. (two days ago) But the code got changed by accident and cant find the solution after spending the day looking for it.

Basically I have a gridview with a bound column containing a value that is hidden.  I have another template column which exists as a trigger - that is  when it is clicked it should bring up an alert screen to show the hidden value from the other column.

It worked beautifully and then pfft.  (shame on me for not printing code or backing up)

Here is what I have left from that code - I have been tryign all sorts of combinations --  The solution was so elegant -  i realize there are alternatives but they are cumbersome

```
    <asp:TemplateField> 
           <ItemTemplate> 
     <asp:Label ID="txtHint" runat="server"> 
        <a href="#" onclick="alert(<%# Eval("mnemonic") %>);"></a> 
     </asp:Label> 
        </ItemTemplate> 
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

thx

Answer (score 0):

Apogoize - i am new to this forum. I was able to locate my previous post(question) which contains the answer:

Here it is;
');">Click to show ID

the " preceing alert was changed to apostrophe and likewise with mathcing apostrophe. - I took out comment  ..clikc to show id' but shouldn't have had any effect.

i also see the original question was raised under 'select row in gridview with javascript"